# python 3.4 py2exe image.open cannot find the images

Tags: python, image, tkinter, exe, py2exe

I am trying to create an executable file of my GUI (which uses 12 images from my computer) but when I create it, the .exe does not run in another computer because it cannot find those 12 images

I have a tree like this

```
project (folder)
--mycode.py (python file)
--setup.py (python file)
--images (folder)
  --image1 (image .jpg)
  --image2 (image .jpg)
  --image3 (image .jpg)
```

then I use py2exe to create the .exe and my tree is now

```
project (folder)
--__pycache__ (folder)
  --mycode.cpython-34.pyc
--dist (folder)
  --mycode.exe (executable file for windows)
  --(and other 22 elements)
--mycode.py (python file)
--setup.py (python file)
--images (folder)
  --Im_0.jpg
  --Im_1.jpg
  --Im_2.jpg
  --...
```

now

I am using these to find my images

```
import os
scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
IM0 = os.path.join(scriptDir, 'Images\\Im_0.jpg')
....
```

then I create the .exe

however when I run the executable it it says

```
"NameError: name '__file__' is not defined"
```

then I try to go to http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI
because py2exe doesn't have a **file** attribute

they say use

```
import os
import jpath

if hasattr(sys,"frozen") and sys.frozen in ("windows_exe", "console_exe"):
  p=jpath.path(os.path.abspath(sys.executable)).dirname()
```

some other people say

```
import JPath class
import JPath.engine #@UnresolvedImport    
import jpath.syntax
from jpath.data import Boolean, Item, List, Map, Null, Number, Pair, String
import jpath.errors as errors
from jpath.utils.messages import JPATH_INTERNAL_ERROR_MESSAGE
from jpath.utils.text import trimTo
import jpath.evaluators
import re
from linearclassification.lib.utils import jpath,chunk,contains,has_subsequence
```

but python show this message

```
ImportError: No module named 'JPath'
```

now I do not know what to do to run my code importing the images that are in the same folder where the .exe is as my tree shows

Comment: Have you specified `jpath` as a required module in `setup.py`?

Comment: no, I thought that I should specify it in mycode.py

Comment: Nope, you have to create a `setup.py` via `distutils` (although you might be able to get away with using `setuptools`...not sure). http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions

Comment: in my setup.py I have     from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['mycode.py'])

Comment: Right. You'll need to tell `setup` what modules you require. This is where `find_packages` in `setuptools` comes in handy.

Comment: so in my setup.py I put if hasattr(sys,"frozen") and sys.frozen in ("windows_exe", "console_exe"):
  p=jpath.path(os.path.abspath(sys.executable)).dirname()??????????, or how do I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

done, the answer is this one

first in mycode.py I put

```
p=os.path.abspath(sys.executable)
IM0 = os.path.join('Images\\Im_0.jpg')
IM1 = os.path.join('Images\\Im_1.jpg')
IM2 = os.path.join('Images\\Im_2.jpg')
...
```

then I create the .exe by calling mycode.py with setup.py
like this

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(
 name="mycode",
 windows =['mycode.py'],
 options = {"py2exe": {"packages": ["encodings"]}}
 )
```

then I go to command prompt change the directory to the folder where setup.py and mycode.py are
and latter I write

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

which create 2 folders

```
--__pycache__ (folder)
  --mycode.cpython-34.pyc
--dist (folder)
  --mycode.exe (executable file for windows)
  --(and other 22 elements)
```

now inside dist (folder) I paste the folder Images (folder) where all my images are and

```
--dist (folder)
  --mycode.exe (executable file for windows)
  --(and other 22 elements)
  --Images (folder)
    --Im_0.jpg
    --Im_1.jpg
    --Im_2.jpg
    --....
```

Done

if somebody has a better method please tell me

thanks anyway